# Hiding row labels

Tags: user-interface, qt4, pyqt

I'm using Qt4 to create a table, using the `QTableWidget` class.

Problem is: I want to hide the row labels (i.e. the numbers). I just care about columns.
I want to get this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ldc.usb.ve](http://www.ldc.usb.ve/docs/qt/images/windowsxp-tableview.png))</sub>

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: mine is not shown from default. how to show it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I was wondering about the same thing. However, I was too lazy to find a solution till you asked. (Thanks!!). Anyway, here is the code that worked for me:

```
    table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
    table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
```

These are actually **QTableView's** methods. Since you use a **QTableWidget** which is a child of **QTableView**, everything works out.

I am not sure whether this is the best way to do this, but the **QHeaderView** documentation recommends this method. To quote the PyQt4 docs-

> **Appearance**
>
>
> QTableWidget and QTableView create default headers. If you want the headers to be     
> visible, you can use setVisible().
>
> **Note**: Each header renders the data for each section itself, and does not rely on a    
> delegate. As a result, calling a header's setItemDelegate() function will have no     
> effect.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm lazy, too. I gave up when I wasn't able to find a property in the qt-Designer which allowed me to do that.

Comment: As of Qt Designer 4.5 (I believe), you can set both the vertical and horizontal header properties right in the property editor.

Comment: Cannot edit answer ("edit queue full"), because is in little detail wrong: "False" --> "false". Just to be correct and make it "copy/pastable".

Answer (score 6):

You can also put your data in a QTableView object and hide the vertical row header with a **hide()** function. Here is the sample code,

```
 QTableView *empview = new QTableView();
 empview->verticalHeader()->hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can just use [method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#headerHidden-prop):

```
setHeaderHidden(true);
```

inherited from **QTreeView**. It was introduced in Qt4.4.